# Selenium web driver scripts for Authenticated view

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-chromedriver

I am new for Automation testing using  selenium  web driver for chrome.I want to test authenticated view from selenium web driver ,so i wrote  code

```
  public  void WriteReviewAfterLogin()
   {string BaseUrl = "http://vps65937-6.lcnservers.com/10300/profile/login.php";
       var driver = new ChromeDriver();   
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(BaseUrl);
   var loginBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("username"));
   loginBox.SendKeys("govinda.silverlight@gmail.com");
   var pwBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));
   pwBox.SendKeys("12345");
   var signinBtn = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[class='btn btn-default signin']"));
   signinBtn.Click();
   const string url = "http://vps65937-6.lcnservers.com/10300/company-reviews/sks-security-53beee89163ce.html";
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
   ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.resizeTo(1024, 768);");
      var reviewTitle = driver.FindElement(By.Id("review_title"));
      reviewTitle.SendKeys("thi  is testing titile");
      var review = driver.FindElement(By.Id("review"));
      review.SendKeys("this is testing");
      var signinBtns = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[class='submitReview']"));
      signinBtns.Click();
      driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://vps65937-6.lcnservers.com/10300/");
   }
```

invoked as

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SeliniumChrome loginSeliniumChrome=new SeliniumChrome();

    loginSeliniumChrome.WriteReviewAfterLogin();

    }
```

When this code runs the login view   is authenticated and redirected to another url,the login state is lost how to   set in log in state in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any use of below mentioned lines in your code. Better to remove these lines because once you will login you will be redirected to below mentioned url.

```
const string url = "http://vps65937-6.lcnservers.com/10300/company-reviews/sks-security-53beee89163ce.html";

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```